# what type of error is this in keras and pleas give me a solution also?

Tags: keras

```
dataset_total = concat((training_set['Milk'], test_set['Milk']), axis = 0)

inputs = dataset_total[len(dataset_total) - len(test_set) - 10:].values

inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)

inputs = sc.transform(inputs)

X_test = []

for i in range(10, 16):

    X_test.append(inputs[i-10:i, 0])

X_test = np.array(X_test)

X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))

predicted_stock_price = regressor.predict(X_test)

predicted_stock_price = sc.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price)
```

Here's is my error?

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)


<ipython-input-26-93b179e798f0> in <module>

----> 1 dataset_total = concat((training_set['Milk'], test_set['Milk']), 
axis = 0)


      2 inputs = dataset_total[len(dataset_total) - len(test_set) - 
10:].values

      3 inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)

      4 inputs = sc.transform(inputs)

      5 X_test = []



IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis 
(`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: please add an explanation paragraph, explaining what you are trying to do.

Comment: are you able to read what is in training_set['Milk'] and test_set['Milk']